# Stop holiday/christmas/spoken word from playing in iTunes DJ?

Tags: playlist, itunes

Whilst I like Herb Albert and his Marijuana Brass Band dropping a christmas phat one, I don't appreciate it when it's July

How can I prevent them from appearing in the playlist?

Answer (score 3):

Make a playlist that includes all your Christmas songs.  Then in all your other playlists, explicitly exclude the Christmas playlist. The DJ can pull from a playlist that isn't the "holiday" mix.

Answer (score 3):

I have added a comment `[xmas]` to all my christmas songs and use this tag to exclude songs from playlists. For iTunes DJ I created a list containing all songs without the tag and used this list as basis for iTunes DJ.

PS: This of course only works if you don't use the comment field for something else.